# Converting hex data stored as a string into a file

Tags: c++, file, fonts, hex, output

Preface:

I am making a simple program in C++ that involves a font. Currently when it executes it creates a data folder that includes text files like a readme, but I haven't found a way to automatically create the .ttf that my program needs to display text. My first instinct was to open up the .ttf in a text editor and try writing that text to a file, but of course that didn't work.

Problem:

I have a file that I converted into hex data like this

```
00 01 00 00 00 10 00 40 00 04 00 c0 4f 53 2f 32
80 8f 7e ff 00 00 8e b8 00 00 00 4e 50 43 4c 54
... 2298 more lines
```

I feel as though I should be able to hard code this hex data into a string located within my project, and then I should be able to use this data to create a .ttf file when my program executes. Unfortunately I have not yet found a way.

Given a string that looks like the above (or one that I could make using find/replace), how would I go about creating a working .ttf file?

Comment: What is the thing that you call "the .ttf" if not a file?  If you already have a file, why do you need to create a file?

Comment: On my computer I just downloaded the file and manually put it into the data folder. I want to be able to give someone the executable and have it work without having them download a font file separately. Basically I want to package the font file within the executable itself (stored as a string of hex data)

Comment: Why not package your program so it installs the resource files that it needs?

Comment: Im not sure what kind of packaging you mean, but I can say that my goal is to make a single executable that can be run to play the game. This executable would create all the necessary resource files. Perhaps I could find a way to make a .app that contains the executable and the resource, but then someone couldn't build my source code on another machine.

I know there are ways to compile a file in your project, but they all seemed to store the file in hex data like above so it wouldn't be much different than just storing the file as a string.

Comment: An installer is a simple program that unpacks the files you need, and then (optionally) runs your main program.

Comment: But that simple program would have to be something like a .exe, which goes against the simple executable style I'm looking for. If I was making a larger project I could see how an installer would be more practical, but since I only need one small file (and will never need anything else), I think hard coding into the executable itself makes the most sense. This way I can take my source code and just compile it on another machine to do cross platform support

Comment: Make a small program that reads the TTF file and writes it out into a binary array (`char ttffile[] = {...}`) in a cpp file. Compile and link the generated cpp file in with the rest of your program source. Now you have a huge array of bytes that represent a ttf file. Nothing wrong with using ofstream.write to dump it back to disk. Only problem after that should be registering the font.

Comment: What might this binary array look like? For example lets just say the file was

    00 01 00 00 00 10 00 40 00 04 00 c0 4f 53 2f 32

What would appear in the {...}. I ask because I did some conversion before. For one I just added 0x before each chunk and I got issues with integer values not fitting into the char size.

Answer (score 0):

First get the hex data for your file, it might look something like this

```
00 01 00 00 00 10 00 40 00 04 00 c0 4f 53 2f 32
80 8f 7e ff 00 00 8e b8 00 00 00 4e 50 43 4c 54
...
```

then, use a text editor with regex support (like sublime text) to get the data looking like this

```
{0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x4f, 0x53, 0x2f, 0x32,
0x80, 0x8f, 0x7e, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8e, 0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4e, 0x50, 0x43, 0x4c, 0x54,
...}
```

Wherever you wish, define a file to output the data to

```
std::ofstream file;
file.open("<path>", std::ios::binary);
```

Create a new .cpp just for this following array since it will be very large and unwieldy. I just created a class with one function `writeHextoFile(std::ofstream& file)` and put the below in it

```
size_t data_len = <number of elements in array>
unsigned char data[data_len] = {<from above>}
file.write((char *)&data[0], data_len);
```

Now, back where you defined your ofstream file, just call `writeHextoFile(file)` and finally close it out with `file.close()`